# CRUD model in rails without using resource and scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I'm new to rails, and I've already learnt how to do CRUD using scaffold and using resource, I wanna know how to Do CRUD without using resource, However what I want to do is create custom methods for CRUD in the controller that will be like the traditional CRUD model. Please help me with this.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that?

Comment: maybe you meant you didn't want to generate model scaffold?
we generate CRUD for resource, without resource it is meaningless

Comment: I just wanted to know how the work flow is without using resources and scaffold, I thought using the custom made method is more comfortable, hence I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for the action index / new / show /  create / edit / update / destroy, this is a convention in Ruby On Rails

If I'm right and if you're trying to change their name using resources in routes.rb (Changing by exemple the new action into def my_restaurant), Rails will render

> Unknown action The action 'new' could not be found for
> RestaurantsController

Netherless, you can create some methods to perform some particular action into the index, and add them in the "private section" you want to hide them to the public. There is no routes attach to this method.

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @restautants = Restaurant.all
      @restaurants.sort_by_name
    end
    
    private
   
    def sort_by_name
     #some action here
    end
end
```

If you want to create your own name method, you can personnalise it but you can't use resources "shortcut" in the routes.rb

by exemple :

```
 #reviews_controller.rb 
 class ReviewsController < AplicationController 
    
    def index 
      @reviews = Reviews.all
    end

    def update
      @review = Review.find(review_params[:id])
    end
    
    def history
     #some action
    end

    private 

    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:liked, :comment, :id)
   end

 end
```

Then add a view
#app/views/reviews/history.html.erb

Don't forget the routes :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    resources :reviews, only: [:index, :update] do
        collection do
          get :history
        end
      end 
 end
```

I hope this will help you and complete the previous answer.

as for your second question :

> I still do have one doubt tho..... Will <%= form_for @post do |f| %>
> this form be enough for new_post and edit_post, will it automatically
> identify them? If that's not enough can you please tell me the what
> comes at new_post.html.erb and edit_post.html.erb....Thanks again for
> the help.

***If the form is the same for your new_post and edit_post***, i may suggest you to put into a partial file. (For this example I used simple_form gem)

```
#app/views/posts/_form.html.erb

<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: "post name" %>
  <%= f.input :photo, as: :file %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class:"btn btn-small btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

and then render the partial in your views new file.

```
#app/views/posts/new.html.erb 

<div>
  <h1>New Post</h1>
</div>
<%= render "form" %>
```

Well I hope I could help you with this answer.
Do not hesitate too to read [ruby documention](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html). You may find more information that you're looking for too.

My answer may be redundant but it's the better way for me to clearly explain it...

Answer (score -1):

In oder to use your own custom methods you need to create them in your controller, setup the route and if needed create an view.

```rb
# PostsController
def create_post
  # Do your create stuff here
end

def read_post
  # Do your read stuff here
end

def update_post
  # Do your update stuff here
end

def delete_post
  # Do your delete stuff here
end
```

```rb
# routes
post '/create_post', to: 'posts#create_post'
get '/read_post/:id', to: 'posts#read_post'
put '/update_post/:id', to: 'posts#update_post'
delete 'delete_post/:id', to: 'posts#delete_post'
```

With the controller and routes setup you will only need a view for the `read_post` method. The best way to do that is create the file: `views/posts/read_post.html.erb`

Comment: Thank you, let me work on this and I'll let you know how it goes, but I still do have one doubt tho..... Will <%= form_for @post do |f| %>    this form be enough for new_post and edit_post, will it automatically identify them? If that's not enough can you please tell me the what comes at new_post.html.erb and edit_post.html.erb....Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score -1):

There is 7 CRUD routes to Create, Read, Update and Delete.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get    "restaurants",          to: "restaurants#index"

  get    "restaurants/new",      to: "restaurants#new",  as: :new_restaurant
  post   "restaurants",          to: "restaurants#create"

  # NB: The `show` route needs to be *after* `new` route.
  get    "restaurants/:id",      to: "restaurants#show", as: :restaurant

  get    "restaurants/:id/edit", to: "restaurants#edit", as: :edit_restaurant
  patch  "restaurants/:id",      to: "restaurants#update"

  delete "restaurants/:id",      to: "restaurants#destroy"
end
```

So once the route create, you can create in the controller, the action that you need

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @restaurants = Restaurant.all 
    end
end
```

and the view

app/views/restaurants/index.html.erb.

The best practice is to create only the routes that you will need and to work in silos.
1 route, 1 controller action, 1 view.

Comment: Thank you, I've worked on this with your help without using resources,but I also wanted custom made user methods, instead of index...I appreciate the help, thank you